# Rabbitmq AMQPConnection Speed

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ and the PhpAmqpLib from Videla.
It takes PHP about 50ms to establish a connection with Rabbit (55ms with connection, 5ms with the connection part commented out).

```
/**
 *
 * @return \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection
 */
private function connect(){
    return new AMQPConnection(
              $this->rabbitHost,
              $this->rabbitPort,
              $this->rabbitUser,
              $this->rabbitPassword);
}
```

Is there a way to make a persistent connection (similar to MySQL) or another trick to speed it up? A message has to be sent to RabbitMQ on every page load.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend [PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php) and pass a [STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) flag ,but you'd have to wire up the connection manually.

I'm not sure if the connection out lives the process though, you'd have to look in to that.

Comment: Ok, so it turns out that the PhpAmqpLib is not the fastest (stream_socket_client is not the bottleneck). Now I use the PECL Amqp library http://us2.php.net/manual/de/book.amqp.php. It takes 1ms to connect, and 5ms for the script: 6ms overall time, vs. 55ms with PhpAmqpLib.